# Error in Java Test Class

Tags: java, decorator

This is the test class that I have an error in and I cant figure out what it is exactly.

```
import java.util.*;
public class EmployeeTest 
{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.setId("100012");
    e.setLastname("Smith"); 
    ResponsibilityDecorator d;
    d = new Recruiter(e);
    d = new CommunityLiaison(e);
    d = new ProductionDesigner(e);      
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
}
```

---

And this the class that links to the test class

```
public class Employee 
{

String id;
String lastname;

Employee(String id, String lastname) 

{

    this.id=id;
    this.lastname=lastname;

}
 EmploymentDuties eduties=new EmploymentDuties();

public EmploymentDuties getDuties()
{
    return eduties;
}
public String toString(){
    return "Duties for this employee: "+eduties.jobtitles;
}

public void setId(String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname)
{
    this.lastname = lastname;
}


}
```

Comment: how can you tell you have an error?! stacktrace? or is your ide marking something?

Comment: Give us a clue : what is the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 8):

There is no *no-args* constructor in `Employee`. Add parameters to use the existing constructor in `EmployeeTest`

```
Employee e = new Employee("100012", "Smith");
```

the statements

```
e.setId("100012");
e.setLastname("Smith");
```

are then redundant and can be removed.

Comment: supply the expected arguments as shown above. Theres actually no need to call `setId` and `setLastname` after doing this :)

Answer (score 1):

Your class Employee defines exactly one constructor: Employee(String, String). Make sure you call it from the EmployeeTest or define a no parameter constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The default constructor is the constructor provided by the java in the absence of any constructor provided by the you.

Once you supplies any constructor , the default constructor is no longer supplied.

you created constructor

```
Employee(String id, String lastname) 

{
```

and   using like

```
Employee e = new Employee();  //not possible
```

Comment: @user2478522 see Reimus answer ,to use it.

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: EmployeeTest : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
 
Could not find the main class: EmployeeTest.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1

Answer (score 0):

The default constructor is the no-argument constructor automatically generated **unless you define another constructor.**

This is the default constructor :

```
 Employee() {}
```

Then you can instantiate objects like :

```
Employee e = new Employee();
```

if you define at least one constructor explicitly , the default constructor is not generated.